# is this a good way to use pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to write an application to create some kind of schedules. Usually I develop in languages like Matlab or Python. This new application will be very computation heavy, we have a current Matlab version, but it takes several minutes to hours to run one instance. Therefore I want to rewrite it using C++.

I just want to ask a basic question concerning pointers, because I'm not so familiar with this concept.

Let's keep it very simply and say I want to create a program to create time schedules. Therefore I write a class "Person" "room" "schedule" and "meeting". 
My plan is to create a schedule which consists of several meetings. Additionally I want to link the meetings to specific rooms and persons. Let’s say I have created 3 persons A B and C and two Rooms r1 and r2. Now I want to create a schedule that consists of three meetings, m1, m2 and m3.

What is now the best way to link all this information? For example I want to be able to pick m1 and see what room it uses and what persons participate. But I also want to be able to pick person A and see what meetings he has, or to select room r1 and look what meetings will take place there. I don't want to simply copy all the objects to all places because I will create a lot of "meeting" objects which are very big. (In my real application I will have ~100 attributes per object, and I will create really a lot of “meeting” objects)

Usually, with different languages, I would simply give everything an id and then only save the id of each meeting or person in the different classes. My idea now, after reading some C++ books, is to use pointers, but I don't know if I can use them in the way I wanted to. My plan is to create my person object and my room object and than create my meetings and use a vector of pointers in each person and room object that consists of all participating meetings. And each meeting consists of some general attributes and a vector of pointers to the participating persons and a pointer to the room. The idea is that this way I don’t need to always compare the ids and I have a direct link to the information.

But I’m really not sure if this is a good idea to do it that way, or is it better to simply give everything a id and store the ids, like meeting m1 has id 100 and all meetings are stored in a vector and if person A participates in meeting 100 and I want to get the information about meeting 100, simply go through the vector of meetings and compare all ids. (Or more likely use a map). And do the same if I want to see each people participating in meeting m1. 
In the book I'm reading the author says you should avoid pointers if possible... Is this also true if I for example use smart pointers?

Thanks for your help and don't forget that I'm rather new to C++ this meansI really want to keep the code simple (I have no idea how to use a database for example)

Comment: Write some simple code and test your ideas. You will see how C++ can best represent your concepts when you do some coding.

Comment: Why are you using raw pointers? You had `std::shared', 'std::unique_ptr`, ' etc. ?

Comment: This is my question, is it a good idea to use smart pointers for this purpose?

Comment: Better to understand pointers through simple code and its advisable to use shared, unique_ptr ( to perform memory management for your program)  but you need to understand the concept of Dynamic memory management.

Comment: It is always a good idea to use smart pointers

Comment: @EdHeal it is a bad idea to use **allways** raw pointers. Smart pointer are **owning** pointer. vector.begin() should definitely be a raw pointer.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**

The best way *to use pointers* with C++ is to use [*smart pointers*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) or [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Usually there's no need to use raw pointers, or manage memory allocation yourself.

Comment: There are many reasons to use raw pointers in C++. Smart pointers are only meant to substitute **owning** raw pointers.

Comment: @manni66 You may elaborate that in your own answer please.

Answer (score -3):

If you're writing a scheduling program, I would recommend using a declarative language. Scheduling is complicated and it is much better to let the computer do the work. Not only does this make it easier for you to program, it makes the programs tiny.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'declarative language'. Yes, I agree, it is very complicated that is the reason why I want to programm it. My example was very easy. My real application needs to schedule observation times of many different stations and to optimize this, which is a lot more complex. At the moment we have a MATLAB code that does that which consists of several 10k lines of code.

Comment: Declarative programming is where you tell the computer what is true and what is false, and computer responds with 1 or more possible solutions.

For example SQL is a declarative language. You tell it what is true (what you're querying) and it replied with all the possible solutions to your query.

For a timetabling program, you can tell it truths about each element of your timetable (for example, what rooms you have, their capacity, etc) and you tell it what is false (for example, it cannot be true that a room is used more than once at the same time).

Comment: No it is not. Declaring something is saying "I can do this".

Comment: In contrast, languages you have been using (matlab, python, java etc) are called Imperative programming languages. They are the opposite of declarative languages, because you tell the computer exactly how to do something.